# Show that Feasible Region of Linear Program is a Single Point

Tags: linear-programming

I have a set of variables $x_i$ for which $x_i \ge 0$, and a set of linear equations relating them: $A \mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{b} $. The typical constraints for a linear program. Is there a general way to check if the region of feasible solutions is actually just a single point? Maybe something analogous to the determinant?

Comment: can you provide the actual problem you're referring to?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the desire for a general method